# remove the character / from a javascript string

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc

Overview: 
I am passing a string to my javascript function, here the code:

**HTML:**

```
<span onclick='fSaveComment(/@item.model.szUserName/)'></span>
```

**Javascript:**

```
function fSaveComment(szUserName) {  

   // If I assign the following line, it strips the first and last characters,
   // if I use szUserName from the function param list, it does not work!!!
   // 
   //szUserName = '/aabbcc/'; 

   myString = szUserName.substr(1, szUserName.length-2);                             
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: what is the purpose of the forward slashes? doesn't look like anything I've seen before

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to correctly quote the username passed to the fSaveComment function

```
<span onclick='fSaveComment("@item.model.szUserName")'></span>
```